Smoothness of function defined via the Cauchy integral formula
I am rereading the beginning of R. Michael Range's Holomorphic Functions and Integral Representations in Several Complex Variables to make sure I can write out some of the proofs explicitly. In theorem [I.1.3], Range proves the Cauchy integral formula for polydiscs: Let $P = P(a, r) \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ a polydisc and $f \in C(\overline{P})$ which is holomorphic in each variable separately. Then for $z \in P$ $$f(z) = (2 \pi i)^{-n} \int_{b_0 P} \frac{f(\zeta) \: d\zeta_1 \cdots d\zeta_n}{(\zeta_1 - z_1) \cdots (\zeta_1 - z_n)}$$ where $b_0 P$ is the distinguished boundary of $P$. Range then follows this theorem with the following corollary [I.1.5]: Let $D$ a domain and $f \in C(D)$ is holomorphic in each variable separately. Then $f \in C^{\infty}(D)$ and in particular $f \in \mathcal{O}(D)$. Here, $f$ is holomorphic if $f \in C^1(D)$ and $f$ satisfies the Cauchy-Riemann equations $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \overline{z_j}}(z) = 0$$ for each $1 \leq j \leq n$ and $z \in D$. Range's proof of this corollary is to apply the Cauchy integral formula to some polydisc $P \subset\subset D$ and differentiate under the integral sign, where he claims that it is legitimate to differentiate under the integral sign as often as needed.
PROBLEM: My idea to show this more rigorously is to use a Leibniz-type rule to legitimize differentiating under the integral. However, I am not sure how to formulate and prove such a rule in this case, because we only know that the partial derivatives $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j}$ are continuous for fixed $(z_1, \ldots, z_{j - 1}, \hat{z_j}, z_{j + 1}, \ldots, z_n)$, and not that they are continuous on the chosen $P \subset\subset D$. Moreover, even if we get such a rule to work, it is not immediately clear to me how this shows us that $f$ is $C^{\infty}$; in particular, I am having trouble seeing that the mixed partial derivatives will be continuous. So a) is this approach correct and if so, what modifications need to be made to a Leibniz type argument to work in the SCV setting and b) allowing differentiation under the integral, how can I see that $f \in C^{\infty}$?

I took a break and came back to the problem just to realize I was being silly. My initial hangup with this problem came from the (very erroneous) idea that partial derivatives of $f$ would appear in the integrand when passing the derivative through (very silly of me). Here is a formulation of an appropriate Leibniz rule along with its proof and application to the problem. I am going to formulate it in terms of polydiscs, but I imagine it can be formulated differently for different domains.
Let $P = P(a, (r_1, \ldots, r_n)), P' \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ be (nonempty) polydiscs and suppose that $\varphi : b_0 P \times \overline{P'} \to \mathbb{C}$ is continuous. Define $g : \overline{P'} \to \mathbb{C}$ by $$g(z) = \int_{b_0 P} \varphi(\zeta, z) \: d\zeta_1 \cdots d\zeta_n$$ Then $g$ is continuous. Moreover, if $\varphi_j = \frac{\partial \varphi}{\partial z_j}$ exists and is continuous on $b_0 P \times \overline{P'}$, then $\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_j}$ exists and is continuous, and $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial z_j}(z) = \int_{b_0 P} \varphi_j(\zeta, z) \: d\zeta_1 \cdots d\zeta_n$$
This proof is somewhat adapted from Conway's proof of the Leibniz rule [IV.2.1] in Functions of One Complex Variable I. The proof that $g$ is continuous is reasonably clear (though I will certainly elaborate if need be), so I will focus on the second statement. Fix some $z \in \overline{P'}$ and let $\epsilon > 0$. We see that $b_0 P \times \overline{P'}$ is compact, so $\varphi_j$ is in fact uniformly continuous on this set and we may find some $\delta > 0$ such that $$|(\zeta, w) - (\zeta', w')| < \delta \implies |\varphi_j(\zeta, w) - \varphi_j(\zeta', w')| < \epsilon$$ In particular, for any $\zeta \in b_0 P$ and whenever $|w_j - z_j| < \delta$ we have $$|\varphi_j(\zeta, z_1, \ldots, z_{j - 1}, w_j, z_{j + 1}, \ldots, z_n) - \varphi_j(\zeta, z)| < \epsilon$$ and moreover we have $$\left|\int_{z_j}^{w_j} [\varphi_j(\zeta, z_1, \ldots, z_{j - 1}, \omega, z_{j + 1}, \ldots, z_n) - \varphi_j(\zeta, z)] \: d\omega\right| \leq \epsilon |w_j - z_j|$$ Note that the existence and continuity of $\varphi_j$ in particular means that $\varphi$ is holomorphic in the variable $z_j$ (and $\varphi_j$ as well), and since $P'$ and its slices are simply connected the above integral is well-defined by path independence. But we now see that for fixed $\zeta \in b_0 P$ and $(z_1, \ldots, z_{j - 1}, \hat{z_j}, z_{j + 1}, \ldots, z_n)$ in the appropriate slice of $P'$, the function $\Phi(w_j) = \varphi(\zeta, z_1, \ldots, z_{j - 1}, w_j, z_{j + 1}, \ldots, z_n) - w_j \varphi(\zeta, z)$ is a primitive for the integrand, so that the above inequality becomes $$|\Phi(w_j) - \Phi(z_j)| = |\varphi(\zeta, z_1, \ldots, w_j, \ldots, z_n) - \varphi(\zeta, z) - (w_j - z_j) \varphi_j(\zeta, z)| \leq \epsilon |w_j - z_j|$$ which, to reiterate, holds for each $\zeta \in b_0 P$ and $(z_1, \ldots, z_{j - 1}, \hat{z_j}, z_{j + 1}, \ldots, z_n)$ in a slice of $P'$. But then for $0 < |w_j - z_j| < \delta$, dividing through by $|w_j - z_j|$ and integrating over $b_0 P$ gives $$\begin{align*} & \quad \:\! \left|\frac{g(z_1, \ldots, w_j, \ldots, z_n) - g(z)}{w_j - z_j} - \int_{b_0 P} \varphi_j(\zeta, z) \: d\zeta_1 \cdots d\zeta_n\right|\\ & = \left|\int_{b_0 P} \left[\frac{\varphi(\zeta, z_1, \ldots, w_j, \ldots, z_n) - \varphi(\zeta, z)}{w_j - z_j} - \varphi_j(\zeta, z)\right] \: d\zeta_1 \cdots d\zeta_n\right|\\ & \leq \int_{b_0 P} \left|\frac{\varphi(\zeta, z_1, \ldots, w_j, \ldots, z_n) - \varphi(\zeta, z)}{w_j - z_j} - \varphi_j(\zeta, z)\right| \: d|\zeta_1| \cdots d|\zeta_n|\\ &\leq \epsilon \: (2 \pi)^n r_1 \cdots r_n\end{align*}$$ and we are done.
Now in the context of the problem: Suppose that $D \subseteq \mathbb{C}^n$ is a domain and that $f \in C(D)$ is holomorphic in each variable separately. Let $P = P(a, r) \subset\subset D$; then by the integral formula we have, for $z \in P$, $$f(z) = (2 \pi i)^{-n} \int_{b_0 P} \frac{f(\zeta) \: d\zeta_1 \cdots d\zeta_n}{(\zeta_1 - z_1)\cdots(\zeta_n - z_n)}$$ Choose a smaller polydisc $P' \subset\subset P$ and define $\varphi : b_0 P \times \overline{P'}$ by $$\varphi(\zeta, z) = \frac{f(\zeta)}{(\zeta_1 - z_1) \cdots (\zeta_n - z_n)}$$ Note that our choice of $P'$ was specifically to guarantee that $z$ is bounded away from $b_0 P$. Hence $\varphi$ is continuous and in fact $\varphi_1, \ldots, \varphi_n$ all exist and are continuous on $b_0 P \times \overline{P'}$, so that by our Leibniz rule $\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j}$ exists and is continuous on $P'$ for each $1 \leq j \leq n$ and we have $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial z_j}(z) = (2 \pi i)^{-n} \int_{b_0 P} \varphi_j(\zeta, z) \: d\zeta_1 \cdots d\zeta_n$$ Now for any multi-index $\alpha \in \mathbb{N}^n$, we see that $$D_z^{\alpha} \varphi(\zeta, z) = \frac{\alpha! f(\zeta)}{(\zeta - z)^{\alpha + 1}}$$ This is always continuous on $b_0 P \times \overline{P'}$, and so by Cauchy's integral formula and repeated application of our Leibniz rule we see that $D^{\alpha} f$ is continuous for any $\alpha$ and so $f \in C^{\infty}(D)$ and in particular $f \in \mathcal{O}(D)$.
